# Cloud Run Error "_access_secret_version: Unable to access secret"

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I'm having issues with a Cloud Run app accessing secrets. The secrets are exposed as environment variables and I have already confirmed that they exist and contain values. Also, the Secret Manager Secret Accessor role is already assigned to the Cloud Run service account. I'm unsure if this is an access issue to only the access_secret_version, like the error states or if it's an issue accessing the secret entirely. Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to pinpoint the source of the issue yet.

[image: Cloud Run Log]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The environment variable is case sensitive. I was using all upper case letters in the name in the Cloud Run variable and my code was set to look for it in all lower case.